# QA Automation script run fails while trying to detect an android app button which has a unique id

Tags: python, android, selenium-webdriver, appium-android, python-appium

I'm working on writing a test automation script for a android app.

I'm using python to write the code and using Appium server to run these tests and using Appium UI inspector to identify elements.

I'm testing on a button for which i got the id from Appium UI inspector but on running the script fails at the point where the code is trying to identify the button.

**python script**

```
el_createConfBtn = self.driver.find_element("id", "**.**.app:id/btnSubmit")
```

**Appium UI inspector**
[image]

**error**

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/masOF.png)

was trying to click on the button. the expectation is Appium identifies the element and then run the code without failing

Comment: Given that the error message tells you `NoSuchElementException` can you confirm that the element actually exists ?   "*An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters*"

Comment: This element exists and has a unique id

Comment: if the element exists, then the search is deficient. Please share sufficient code for others to help identify the error and fix:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you write an xpath selector like `//android.widget.Button[@resource-id='yourid']`?

Are you sure the button is loaded/clickable yet when you're trying to click?

Answer (score 0):

The main thing 
The screenshot that you attached shows **resource-id** not **ID**, therefore, most likely, an error occurs, accordingly you should use **XPath**
It will be better to use AppiumBy.ID instead "id", as well

```
  el_createConfBtn = self.driver.find_element(AppiumBy.XPATH, "locator")
```

Simple example:

```
class BaseClass:
  
  
  def click(self, locator: Tuple[By, str]):
      self.driver.find_element(*locator).click()

class PO(BaseClass):
      EL_LOCATOR = (AppiumBy.ID, "**.**.app:id/btnSubmit")

   def tap_on_btn(self):
       self.click(self.EL_LOCATOR)
```

___________________

```
def tap(self, locator):
        try:
            locator = self.wait.until(
                ec.visibility_of_element_located(locator))
            locator.click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
           print('')
```

___________________

```
  def click(self, locator_string):
    locator = self.get_locator(locator_string)
    if str(locator_string[0]).startswith("xpath"):
        self.driver.find_element(MobileBy.XPATH, str(locator)).click()
    elif str(locator_string[0]).startswith("accessibility"):
        self.driver.find_element(MobileBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, str(locator)).click()

def get_locator(locator_with_type):
    locator = locator_with_type[1]
    return locator
```